# Ogre/Mogre: Camera two point perspective

Tags: 3d, ogre, perspectivecamera

I'm displaying a scene with some cubes in it. The camera uses persective. Everything works great, but I'd like the vertical lines to be parallel (two point perspective: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)#Two-point_perspective).

When viewing a cube from the front:

What I want:

```
+-----+
|     |
|     |
+-----+
```

What I'm getting (exaggerated):

```
+--------+
 \      /
  \    /
   +--+
```

I've tried fiddling with the camera's FOV, but to no avail.

**My attempt so far:**

```
Camera = SceneManager.CreateCamera(CameraName);
float q = 45;
float d = 5000f;
Matrix4 m = new Matrix4(
    1, 0, 0, (float)(Math.Sin(q)/d),
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, (float)(Math.Cos(q)/d),
    0, 0, 0, 0
    );
Camera.SetCustomProjectionMatrix(true, m);
```

Comment: Fiddling with the field of view won't help you. I've not come across the 2 point perspective in computer graphics before - but I guess it *should* be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The University of Berkeley has a page on the different perspective transformations and the matrices you need to use. The two-point perspective transformation is:

```
  _                    _
 |  1   0   0 sin(q)/d  |
 |  0   1   0     0     |
 |  0   0   1 cos(q)/d  |
 |_ 0   0   0     0    _|
```

Where `q` is the angle used to rotate the points (rather than the axes) and `d` is unexplained(!) but I think it's the distance of the camera from the focal plane.

[image]

[Source](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~barsky/perspective.html)

Comment: Thank you for your fast reply. I've set `Camera.ProjectionType = ProjectionType.PT_ORTHOGRAPHIC;` but that results in all axes being parallel, not just the vertical (y?) one. I also tried adding `Camera.SetCustomProjectionMatrix(true, new Matrix4(1,0,0,0, 0,1,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,1));` but then I just get solid colors (as if the camera is zoomed in very, very close).

Comment: @TeunvanVegchel - you can't have parallel projection on one axis and perspective on the others.

Comment: Just to be sure, I found what I want on wikipedia: [Two point perspective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perspective_(graphical)#Two-point_perspective). But Ogre doesn't support this?

Comment: @TeunvanVegchel - I've updated my answer based on the new information

Comment: Thanks once more! I've tried a whole range of values for d (0...1, 1...100, 1000+, also negative) but my screen remains blank.

See my updated answer for my setup so far.

Comment: Teun you cannot pass random values to the projection matrix. Setting the projection matrix to identity results in no projection at all (your points are in 2D). You need to consider Ogre's matrix notation (row or column major) and then adapt the matrix provided to suit it. Have you tried taking the transpose of the matrix to see if it works better ?

Comment: Matrix needs to be transposed

Comment: I finally got something working. There are still lots of problems however. I've decided this is no longer worth pursuing.

Comment: Hey, before you gave up, @Teun van Vegchel, how was your code? I am looking into the same problem.